# Loading pre-trained Keras model, and merging with branching model to create multi-input

Tags: keras, lstm

I have pre-trained a sequential model using the Keras fuctional API.

Now, I need to load the model, remove the top and concatenate it with a branching side model, and train the new full model.

I am interested in retaining the first pre-trained layers of the main model.

I believe the issue is to set up the right inputs and outputs so that the model connects correctly and compiles. I think there is currently a disconnect between the new input layer of the main model, and the rest of the main model.

The number of layers in the pre-trained model is dynamic. This is the motivation for loading the model and change it rather than using config and weights to re-configure the pre-trained layers in the complete model. I have not found a working way of hardcoding the configuration of the complete model with config and weights that works with changing number of pre-trained layers.

UPDATE: To make it clearer what the issue is, I need to set up a connected graph. The error message is 'ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("Pretrain_input:0", shape=(?, 4, 105), dtype=float32) at layer "Pretrain_input". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []'

```
##### MAIN MODEL #####

# loading pretrained model
main_model = load_model('models/main_model.h5')


# saving the output layer for reconstruction later
config_output_layer = main_model.layers[-1].get_config()
weights_output_layer = main_model.layers[-1].get_weights()


# removing the first and last layer (not sure if I need to remove the first layer, but I do this as I need an explicit 'entry point' for later concatenation with branching model later and re-compiling )
main_model.layers.pop(0)
main_model.layers.pop(-1)


# new first layer, for input later
main_input = Input(
    shape=(x_train_main.shape[1], x_train_main.shape[2]),
    name='Main_input')


# reconstructing last layer
main_output = Dense.from_config(config_last_layer)(main_model.output)


# re-defining the main model
new_main_model = Model(inputs=main_input, outputs=main_output)


 ##### BRANCHING MODEL #####   


branch_visible = Input(
    shape=(x_train_branch.shape[1], x_train_branch.shape[2]),
    name='Branch_input')


branch_hidden_0 = LSTM(
    units=units_lstm_layer,
    return_sequences=True,
    name='Branch_hidden_0'
)(branch_visible)


branch_dense = Dense(
    units=units_dense_layer,
    name='Branch_dense'
)(branch_hidden_0)


##### CONCAT THE MAIN AND THE BRANCH #####

concatenated_output = Concatenate(axis=-1)([main_output, branch_dense])


activation_layer = Dense(
    units=units_activation_layer,
    activation=activation,
    name='Activation'
)(concatenated_output)


final_model = Model(inputs=[main_visible, branch_visible], outputs=activation_layer)
```

Comment: Is there a specific issue you are trying to fix?

Comment: Yes, currently the graph is disconnected. I need to set up a complete connected graph.

Comment: `main_output = Dense.from_config(config_last_layer)(main_model.output)` is still pointing to the old output of the model. Pass `main_model.layers[-1]` or similar

Comment: Thank you, but that returns `ValueError: Layer Dense_main was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'keras.layers.recurrent.LSTM'>. Full input: [<keras.layers.recurrent.LSTM object at 0x14345bd68>]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.`

Comment: I also tried `main_model.layers[-1].output.` `ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("Pretrain_input:0", shape=(?, 4, 105), dtype=float32) at layer "Pretrain_input". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []`

Comment: It looks like that's related to you pooping off the input. Try leaving it there.